# How do you add 2 string variable counts together in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

Here is my current code in the controller.

```
@rating = (@approvals.count / @user.pages.count) + ( @awards.count / @user.stories.count )
```

When I call each of these variables separately, they come up as the numbers they should.  When I add them together, the sum seems to be either 1 or 0.  Is there a certain way of adding variable counts together?

I have looked at other posts and either can't find what I need or am not understanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you need to convert them to floats. Try to the `to_f` method.

```
@rating = (@approvals.count.to_f / @user.pages.count) + ( @awards.count.to_f / @user.stories.count )
```

Comment: It should be noted that this needs to happen because of the division only, since something like `4/10`'s *integer* result is `0`.